# Yii2 Insert data type in Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, types, yii2

I use:

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('test');
$arrInsert = ['username' => 'test',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'testmongo' => ['test1' => '56',
                                            'test2' => true,
                                            'test3' => '10/3/2012'],

                        ];
$collection->insert($arrInsert);
```

All data insert to mongodb with data type is String, but I want test1 is Int32, test2 is Boolean, test3 is datetime,... Plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `56` instead of `'56'`, `1` instead of `true` and dateTime format instead of string:

```
'test1' => 56
'test2' => 1,
'test3' => DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/3/2012')],
```

Comment: Note that form data works differently in Yii2, as such if this data is submitted through GET or POST it will need a lot more work on it and validators changing etc